# How do i over come the undefined offset 0 notices in php

Tags: php

How do i over come the undefined offset 0 notices in php

I have some statements in php  which contains some arrays which are causing this notices . 
But inoorder to fix this iam using empty() in php .

```
$val= array(    
    'codes' => $this->arr1['BAC'],
    'lines' => $this->arr1['array1'][0]['RACE']  // this is the statement causing undefined offset 0
);

if(!empty( $this->arr1['array1'])){
$val= array(    
    'codes' => $this->arr1['BAC'],
    'lines' => $this->arr1['array1'][0]['RACE']  // this is the statement causing undefined offset 0
);
}
```

would the above be recommended . But my question if i put them in if() .Can the $val  be accessed  outside the if()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test `isset($this->arr1['array1']['0']['RACE'])` and you'll know whether you can use it or not.

You can also turn off notices (not recommended though):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: +1 for isset, -1 for turning off notices that are very valuable during development.

Comment: I edited my post to mention it's not recommended. I wouldn't use this approach myself, but it could be valuable to know that it is possible to turn them off.

Comment: But using `isset()` makes the code longer and more complex.. In one section of my application it made the code unreadable since there are too many `isset()`s .. Not sure if there is any alternative or if I can just ignore all those notices..

Answer (score 1):

Check the indexes of array is  set before using

```
    if(isset($this->arr1['array1'][0]['RACE']))
    {
      $val= array(    
        'codes' => $this->arr1['BAC'],
        'lines' => $this->arr1['array1'][0]['RACE']  // this is the statement causing undefined offset 0
    );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable scope in PHP is at the function level. Defining a variable inside an if()/while()/for()/do() construct is the same as defining them outside the construct. However, variables will not leak out of a function, nor into a function:

```
$x = 'a';
if (1 == 1) {
   echo $x; // 'a'
   $y = 'b';
}
echo $y; // 'b'

function p() {
   echo $y; // null/blank/does not exist
   $z = 'c';
}
echo $z; // null/blank/does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

The $val can be accessed outside the if, so long as the the if is satisfied.